# Http request from inside express route

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

When a user visits the route i want to fetch some data before rendering the page with jade/pug, passing that data.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  asyncHttp()
    .then(data => {
      res.render('routeToRender', {
        title: 'routeToRender', data: data
      })
    })
    .catch(err=>{log(err})
})
```

I get the "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent." Probably because my asyncHttp sets some Headers. How do i isolate that request from the route?

Comment: what does the asyncHttp do? Make sure it does not have access to res so it can't set headers.

Comment: That's because you're calling render after the response cycle has ended. That's an asynchronous call since it returns a promise. Look into generators or async/await.

Comment: @natnai it's perfectly fine to make async calls in Express route handlers.

Comment: @robertklep It is but it also requires some thought. If you do this you must be sure not to pass the response on or it might be sent before you can do what you wanted in your async function, which I suspect is what's happening in this case. That's because res.render in the success callback tries to set headers on the res object, but that res object is alreay sent somewhere down the middleware chain.

Comment: asynHttp() is a promisified get request using the request module.

Comment: @natnai true, but if `asyncHttp()` was called `syncHttp()` (and were synchronous), and it would return a response, the same error would be thrown. The issue isn't that an async function is being called, it's that something is being done with the response object that shouldn't be done to it :)

Comment: @NashEquilibro how can `asyncHttp()` set response headers if it doesn't get passed `res`?

Comment: @robertklep agreed. I think this TS is not showing the complete route handler. Something is happening either before or after this in the chain. If he really didn't call next() in this function, then its more likely something further up already sent the response. That's why async calls in routes are hard. Hard to debug without more context.

Comment: @robertklep that is what i do not understand. Is the problem, that the asyncHttp() ends the response cycle like natnai commented? And the res.render() tries to set headers after they are already sent?

Comment: asyncHttp doesn't have access to res. Did you call next in this handler? If not, look upstream.

Comment: @NashEquilibro does the error disappear when you replace the entire contents of the route handler with `res.render('routeToRender', ...)` (or even just a plain `res.send('hello world')`)? If `asyncHttp()` doesn't get the `res` object, it's very likely not the cause of the error (and I suspect it's a middleware).

Comment: Yes the error disappears if i take the asynHttp() out.

Comment: The page renders fine even with the error popping up btw.

Comment: Can you share the internals of `asyncHttp`?

Comment: @NashEquilibro all of it, please.

Comment: something like: return new promise((resolve,reject)=>{request.get({url: 'http://api', headers: {header: xxx}}, function(err,res,data) {if (!err) {resolve(data)} else {reject(err)}})})

Comment: I am going to search upstream as was suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out asynchronous http request are fine in the route as long as you do not change the res object.

The mistake was upstream in an res.redirect() to the route, that was missing a return statement.

I could not conclude why the asyncHttp() brought it to light and the error does not show up without it.